# Php active class to main navigation item when sub link is active

Tags: php, html

How to add a "active" class to main navigation item when child page is active.

Lets say, there are three main links example as "Components", "About Us", and "Contact" so when I go to components page and there are some child pages example "Accordion", "Alerts", "Badge" and so on and If I click any of the child page example "Accordion" then the Accordion page nav should be active as well as main nav which is Components page should be active.

I have used something like this `<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'accordion.php' ? 'active' : ''; ?>` but how do I make main nav item also active when in child pages?

```
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'components.php' ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
      <a href="components">Components</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'about-us.php' ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
      <a href="about-us">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'contact.php' ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
      <a href="contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<sidemenu class="sidemenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'accordion.php' ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
      <a href="/components/accordion">Accordion</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'alerts.php' ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
      <a href="/components/alerts">Alerts</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'badge.php' ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
      <a href="/components/badge">Badge</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'breadcrumb.php' ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
      <a href="/components/breadcrumb">Breadcrumb</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</sidemenu>`
```

I have tried many php examples like this  but I am not sure how to make main also active when in child page which is part of components.

Comment: Can you help me how to do this, I am a beginner in PHP